# Istio AuthService not redirecting on initial request

Tags: openid-connect, azure-aks, istio

I am attempting to integrate OIDC with Istio using the [AuthService](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/authservice) project. I've been following the [bookinfo-example](https://github.com/istio-ecosystem/authservice/tree/master/bookinfo-example) with the one big change being that I'm trying to use Azure AAD's OIDC support for my IDP instead of Google. However, I've as yet been unable to get the AuthService to redirect my request to the IDP for sign-in. If I leave the RequestAuthentication and AuthorizationPolicy objects undeployed, then I'm able to access the /productpage with no problem (but with no redirect to login) and if I *do* deploy those objects, I'm simply met with an "Access Denied" error (and, again, no redirect for login).

Here's what my setup looks like so far:

```
K8S: Azure Kubernetes Service
Istio: 1.18.2
Authservice: 0.5.3
```

1. authservice and bookinfo pods are deployed, everything is running, and Istio sidecars are injected:

```
    
    kubectl -n default get pods
    
    NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    
    authservice-6bbff64c85-mblwn      2/2     Running   0          20m
    
    details-v1-6997d94bb9-xblrj       2/2     Running   0          55m
    
    productpage-v1-58b4c9bff8-n2rfz   2/2     Running   0          55m
    
    ratings-v1-b8f8fcf49-s7kqt        2/2     Running   0          55m
    
    reviews-v1-5896f547f5-t9htt       2/2     Running   0          55m
    
    reviews-v2-5d99885bc9-qcd8h       2/2     Running   0          55m
    
    reviews-v3-589cb4d56c-gw7xj       2/2     Running   0          55m
```

2. I've made the change to the Mesh config to enable the envoyExtAuthzGrpc extensionProvider for the AuthService:

```
    kubectl edit cm -n istio-system

    mesh: |-
      accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
      extensionProviders:
      - name: "authservice-grpc"
        envoyExtAuthzGrpc:
          service: authservice.default.svc.cluster.local
          port: "10003"
      defaultConfig:
        concurrency: 16
        discoveryAddress: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
        image:
...
```

3. The authservice container looks to be in OK shape. The readiness probe failed a few times as it was starting, but it shows as "Ready" now. Everything else seems to look good at first blush:

```
    Containers:
      authservice:
       Container ID:   
       containerd://74486624f79cf357f98244e84f53187506391ce2d715ef73d255375a6710f846
       Image:          dtr.mycompany.com/prhodes1/authservice:0.5.3
       Image ID:       dtr.mycompany.com/prhodes1/authservice@sha256:eeb082929ebf22bebd3141f23916694add1e4ab607b2c15ffa30a919998a6528
       Port:           10003/TCP
       Host Port:      0/TCP
       State:          Running
        Started:      Mon, 16 Oct 2023 14:38:24 -0400
       Ready:          True
       Restart Count:  0
       Readiness:      http-get http://:15020/app-health/authservice/readyz delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
```

4. The Gateway seems OK. And I can access the page via the Gateway OK, as long as the RequestAuthentication and AuthorizationPolicy aren't deployed, so I don't *think* there's any issue here:

```
    kubectl -n default describe gw
    Name:         bookinfo-gateway
    Namespace:    default
    Labels:       
    Annotations:  
    API Version:  networking.istio.io/v1beta1
    Kind:         Gateway
    Metadata:
      Creation Timestamp:  2023-10-16T18:38:22Z
      Generation:          1
      Resource Version:    59762766
      UID:                 9ab0c00c-892f-4ad1-99da-7f04e1e9b877
    Spec:
      Selector:
        Istio:  ingressgateway
      Servers:
        Hosts:
          istio-oidc.mycompany.com
        Port:
          Name:      https-443
          Number:    443
          Protocol:  HTTPS
        Tls:
          Credential Name:  ingress-tls-cert
          Mode:             SIMPLE
    Events:
```

5. My values.yaml looks like this:

```
    authservice:
      image: dtr.mycompany.com/prhodes1/authservice:0.5.3
      # image: ghcr.io/istio-ecosystem/authservice/authservice:0.5.3
      # How the authservice will be enabled and enforced.
      # This can be at ingress (by default) or at application sidecar.
      enforcingMode: ingress
    
    oidc:
      idpURL: https://account.microsoft.com/account/Account
      authorizationURI: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
      tokenURI: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token"
      clientID: your-client-id
      clientSecret: your-client-secret
      # JSON string containing the identity provider's public key for validating id token.
      # jwks: ""
```

EDIT: I thought maybe the problem was that I didn't have the EnvoyFilter, declared in "productpage-external-authz-envoyfilter-sidecar.yaml", deployed. The README doesn't seem to mention that file, so not sure if it's needed by default or not. But I deployed that and it didn't make any different, FWIW.

Anybody have any thoughts on what could be going on here?